# tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 199, 161) for input KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, spectrogram

feature = X_test_features[index]

prob = model3.predict(feature.reshape(1,-1,))

if (prob[0][0] < 0.5):
pred='emergency'
else:
pred='non emergency'

print("Prediction:",pred)

### WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 199, 161) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 199, 161), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_3'), name='input_3', description="created by layer 'input_3'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None).

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2 feature = X_test_features[index]
3
----> 4 prob = model3.predict(feature.reshape(1,-1,))
5
6 if (prob[0][0] < 0.5):

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.predict_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
    return self(x, training=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_2" (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "conv1d_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, None)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

Comment: Hi @AMIR, please share the Minimal Reproducible Code so that we can replicate the error and assist you. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks but..i have solved that...@Tfer3